# Check whether a line in my text file contains letters

Tags: python, regex, nlp

How can I check whether a line in my text file contains letters?
I am trying below code, but unable to check:

```
with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]',str(line)):
            print( "line contains letters" )
```

Comment: `any(char.isalpha() for char in line)`

Comment: @RoadRunner Or `isalnum()`, give the regex the OP tried using.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Indeed, I based that code off the title.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, i already tried that.

Comment: but, while reading from another text file, it is not able to recognize the letter pattern.

Comment: I am new to python, so  Please inform whether I am missing on the encoding(ASCII, Unicode, etc) point?.